# Preguntas sobre el subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Observé varias oraciones. Querría comprobar si entiendo correctamente el uso del subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto en ellas.

Del libro "El Arte de no amargarse la vida" (España):

*"Ahora me **parece** increíble que **hubiese ocultado** algo así desde los 17 años."*

En este ejemplo el significado puede ser: "*It now seems incredible to me if you would hide something like this since you were 17.*"

Mientras tanto, si estuviera este ejemplo: "*Ahora me **parece** increíble que **ocultara** algo así desde los 17 años.*" el significado sería: "*It now seems incredible to me that you really did hide something like this since you were 17.*"

De la serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

***"Hubieses preferido** que **fuera** yo, ¿verdad? El que murió en el atentado, **hubieses preferido** que **fuera** yo en lugar de Gorka."*

Aquí no entiendo la razón concreta por la que el subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto fue usado. Supongo que:

1. El acto de "preferir" sería el primero antes de que el hablante habría muerto.

o

2. Con decir "hubieses preferido" el hablante solo supone de lo que piensa esta otra persona en lo que el prefería que sucedera.

¿Es correcto el entendimiento?

P.S. Les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores  si hay algunos. Especialmente en mis preguntas en el uso de tiempos verbales.

Comment: En el segundo ejemplo, también es válido el condicional compuesto (y en mi opinión es la forma originalmente correcta, aunque ahora valen las dos), "**Habrías preferido** que fuera yo". Más información [aquí](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20de%20subjuntivo%20-%20formas%20-ra%20y%20-se.htm), en el apartado "Con los verbos modales". Aunque "preferir" no está en la lista, la sustitución  del condicional compuesto por el pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo es también común con ese verbo.

Comment: @wimi Sí, yo tambíen pensaba en que "habrías preferido" es valido en este caso (porque en el segundo ejemplo pensaba en que la segunda sugerencia sería correcta).

Comment: No es idiomático decir "¿Es correcto el entendimiento?". Mejor: "¿He entendido bien/correctamente?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomemos la primera oración y la que inventaste para hacer el contraste:

1. "Ahora me parece increíble que hubiese ocultado algo así desde los 17 años."
2. "Ahora me parece increíble que ocultara algo así desde los 17 años."

**El significado es el mismo.** En inglés sería: "It now seems incredible to me that you hid something like this since you were 17." El subjuntivo está ahí *because of reasons*. La oración 1 es un poco rara porque la correlación entre tiempos verbales suena mal, pero quizá sea sólo yo.

La clave es que *parece* está en modo indicativo y la subordinada está precedida por *que*, así que esto no es un contrafáctico. Simplemente algo parece increíble. La intención del hablante es ambigua: decir "X me parece increíble" no es lo mismo que decir "No puedo creer en X". Puede serlo o no. Si el hablante quisiera expresar abiertamente su descreimiento, debería decir:

1. "Ahora me parecería increíble que hubieras ocultado..."
2. "Ahora me parecería increíble si hubieras ocultado..."

Estas dos alternativas usan el condicional. Es de hecho un truco: no es que "parecería increíble (pero no lo parece)", sino una forma de decir indirectamente: "sería increíble si hubiera ocurrido realmente, cosa que no creo" ("it would be incredible if it had actually happened, which I don't believe it did").

La oración 1 es una expresión de descreimiento (lo que piensa el hablante). La oración 2, que usa *si* en vez de *que*, es más fuerte: el hablante está refiriéndose al asunto como algo totalmente hipotético.

En cuanto a la otra oración, no se trata más que de una sustitución común. El condicional y el subjuntivo se confunden hace tiempo en español. Donde dice *hubieses* podría haber dicho *habrías*. De hecho, ese lugar de la oración no es una posición donde sea correcto usar un subjuntivo como tal.

Hay un caso donde el subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto aparece en una posición similar, fuera de toda subordinada, para expresar deseos contrafácticos. Se usa de manera coloquial. Por ejemplo:

- "Lo hubieras pensado antes."

Esto es una elipsis: "Sería mejor si lo hubieras pensado antes." O bien "Desearía que lo hubieras pensado antes." No es el mismo caso que en tu oración de ejemplo.